# Countries List with images webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a web service that you can call and get the list of countries and links to images of the flags to each nation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallery_of_sovereign-state_flags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.geognos.com/geo/en/world-countries-API.html seems to be nice.

Comment: i don't know how to implement the ajax call but what would be the url Im looking for when I process a request

Answer (score 4):

Been the author of the above API mentioned by Erik above- I am willing to help.
If you need the flag of a particular country it is as simple as
requesting it: http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/GR.png

In order to get a Json formatted output of all world countries you have to issue an HTTP `GET` request to http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json
You will receive a reply with information about all world countries. For each and every country there is a field called "SeqID".
A png image of all flags arranged vertically is provided  in: http://www.geognos.com/media/flags/world-countries-flags-80X40.png and: http://www.geognos.com/media/flags/world-countries-flags-32X16.png. These images can be used for serving individual flags as image sprites by offsetting vertical position using css sprites techniques. Offset values can be calculated by using the “IdSeq” field of the “info” request and image dimensions. This is the most efficient way for displaying lots of flags. For an example of using sprites you can look at the source code of the following page:http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/IT.html

You can contact me if you need any further help.
Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

This service provides flags in SVG.

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

You can also search for a specific country(Case Insensitive).

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/{name}

For Example, if you want to search Pakistan this should be your URL.

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/capital/pakistan

You will get a JSON Resonance in Return

```
[{"name":"Pakistan","topLevelDomain":[".pk"],"alpha2Code":"PK","alpha3Code":"PAK","callingCodes":["92"],"capital":"Islamabad","altSpellings":["PK","Pākistān","Islamic Republic of Pakistan","Islāmī Jumhūriya'eh Pākistān"],"region":"Asia","subregion":"Southern Asia","population":194125062,"latlng":[30.0,70.0],"demonym":"Pakistani","area":881912.0,"gini":30.0,"timezones":["UTC+05:00"],"borders":["AFG","CHN","IND","IRN"],"nativeName":"Pakistan","numericCode":"586","currencies":[{"code":"PKR","name":"Pakistani rupee","symbol":"₨"}],"languages":[{"iso639_1":"en","iso639_2":"eng","name":"English","nativeName":"English"},{"iso639_1":"ur","iso639_2":"urd","name":"Urdu","nativeName":"اردو"}],"translations":{"de":"Pakistan","es":"Pakistán","fr":"Pakistan","ja":"パキスタン","it":"Pakistan","br":"Paquistão","pt":"Paquistão","nl":"Pakistan","hr":"Pakistan","fa":"پاکستان"},"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/pak.svg","regionalBlocs":[{"acronym":"SAARC","name":"South Asian Association for Regional Cooperation","otherAcronyms":[],"otherNames":[]}],"cioc":"PAK"}]
```

The flag image URL is in the "flag" key.

Source: https://restcountries.eu/